# Go: Posting with Payload/Post Body

Tags: go

Trying to accomplish a HTTP Post in Go:

Posting to: `apiUrl`

Payload/Post Body (expected as a json string): `postBody`

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
cannot use postBodyJson (type []byte) as type io.Reader in argument to http.Post: 
    []byte does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    var postBody = []string{
        "http://google.com",
        "http://facebook.com",
        "http://youtube.com",
        "http://yahoo.com",
        "http://twitter.com",
        "http://live.com",
    }
    requestUrl := "http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics"

    postBodyJson, _ := json.Marshal(postBody)

    resp, err := http.Post(requestUrl, "application/json", postBodyJson)
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

Comment: What version of go are you using? This doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: go version go1.3 windows/amd64. Everything should compile just fine except for the http.Post line, which is what I need the help with.

Comment: It does not compile because your requestUrl variable isn't defined. I'm not quite sure what you're actually trying to do here. I suggest you take a look at the http package to really understand how it works. Did you copy this code from somewhere or you built it yourself?

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the language basics. `http.Post()` accepts an `io.Reader` as the body. You should read how [Interfaces](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) work, probably a little about the HTTP protocol and if you need JSON, read the doc about the [encoding/json](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package.
Also: you are not even importing the `encoding/json` package. That will not compile.

Comment: You're all exactly right. Very sorry for the code that didn't compile. I have edited it.

Comment: Also, I should have mentioned my error in the above post. I have added that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    var postBody = []string{
        "http://google.com",
        "http://facebook.com",
        "http://youtube.com",
        "http://yahoo.com",
        "http://twitter.com",
        "http://live.com",
    }
    apiUrl := "http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics"

    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    enc := json.NewEncoder(buf)
    err := enc.Encode(postBody)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    resp, err := http.Post(apiUrl, "application/json", buf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

Something like this might work. But as I already said in the comments, you should familiarize yourself with the language a little more. When you post code, make sure it compiles.

Comment: Answers on golang questions are all so rude. Downvotes and snark for everyone.